# Storing Tracked Images in a Database vs in a Directory

Tags: mysql

I need to store the X most requested images on my website. Each image is about 20-50KB. It will be easy at first as I have 0 images, but once I go X+1 I'll need to remove the least requested images to bring me back to X.

I was thinking of using a database on each image request. Logging the file name and then either loading the image locally or loading the image remotely. If I'm under X and I don't have the image locally then I'll load the image remotely and save a copy locally for future use. If I'm over X I'll delete the least requested image from the database and locally.

Then it hit me, I could store the image content inside the database. I have to connect to the database anyways, and it would make purging the file really easy.

How much of a performance sin would storing images in a database be? And if its bad, is there a better approach?

Comment: As a rule-of-thumb, storing images under 100k in the db is fine. Anything larger is probably best stored in the file server, with the path stored in the db. But this is just a guide.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact performance impact as it depends on a lot of factors, why not give it a try yourself? Add 10000 images (same image for example) and check which manages to perform the given task faster.

You can store the image in the DB with 2 columns, one being the header `image/png` and one being the body which are the image bytes as a base64 encoded string.

Having the image in the database would also mean that you have to invoke some server side logic and establish a db connection each time you want to fetch an image, something that you can skip with regular files.

But again, these days computers are powerful and the difference might be insignificant for you.